# gulp-jshint package: How to send parameters (without .jshintrc file)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, jshint

I'm currently trying to migrate a grunt project to a gulp project. Actually, in the gruntfile I have (for the jshint task) something like this:

`jshint: {
    options: {
        trailing:true,
        evil:false,
        indent:4,
        undef:true,
        unused:true,
        node:false,
        browser:false,
        loopfunc:true,
        devel:false
    },
    default: {
        options: {
            browser:true,
            globals: {
                define:true
            }
        },
        src: [basePath + "js/**/*.js"]
    }
}`

So, when I write "grunt jshint" in the terminal it seems to work fine. However, in the gulpfile I wrote this:

`gulp.task("jshint", function() {
    return gulp.src( basePath + "js/**/*.js" )
        .pipe( jshint( { "trailing": true,..., "globals": true } ) )
        .pipe( jshint.reporter("default") );
});`

But when I write "gulp jshint" in terminal, it crashes.

My question is: Is there a way to send jshint parameters without .jshintrc file with the gulp-jshint node package? (I've already read the documentation in the npm site, but I dont undestand the "lookup" option)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

globals is an array, not true false, here is my example. lookup works just like you were thinking.

```
gulp.src(files.backend)
    .pipe(jshint({ "lookup": false, /* other options */ "globals": ['$']}))
    .pipe(jshint.reporter(stylish))
    .on('error', gutil.log);
```

Comment: To elaborate, globals is either false or an array of values. http://www.jshint.com/docs/